# How to use a function to define the headerShown option of screenOption property of a react native navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use a function to set the headerShown option to true or false like below:

```
screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
      headerShown: () => {
        if(route.name !== 'Home'){
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
})}
```

The arrow function above doesn't seem to fit the expected syntax as it get flagged as unexpected type error.

What has worked:

```
screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
      headerShown: route.name !== 'Home' ? false : true
})}
```

Is there a way to use the arrow function so I do more with it?

Comment: You can override screenOptions on a per-screen basis (if none if provided, it will fall back to the default). If you're trying to set it on a per-screen basis, simply add the screenOptions object to the screen you want to be different.

Comment: Yeah, true. But I didn't want to have to do it for all the screens individually. The condition covered the scenario I want for now. Maybe later, I might change it. But not at the moment.

Comment: You set a default one in the navigator, and you only have to override the ones you want them to differ on. It's no different than your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found what could work.

I just created an external accessible function and then called it from the headerShown property value. It is not an arrow function, but it does work and fits the scenario I was trying to cover.

```
function headerShownFunction (route) {
  if(route.name === 'Home'){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

// Then within the screenOptions block...
screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
      headerShown: headShownFunction(route)
})}
```

This actually works. Not sure why I didn't think of it earlier.

Comment: It works because you're evaluating the function instead of returning the function. This solution is equivalent to making the original code an IIFE.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Using IIFE actually works.